# onClick function is possibly null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onclick, react-props

I have a props function that is giving me an error that says object is possibly null.

```
import {Dropdown} from "react-bootstrap";
interface GenreButtonProps {
    key: number;
    id: number | null;
    genre: string;
    filterByGenre(id: string | null): void;
}
export default function GenreButton(props: GenreButtonProps) {
    return (
        <Dropdown.Item as={'button'} onClick={() => props.filterByGenre(props.id.toString())}>{props.genre}</Dropdown.Item>
    )
}
```

The function is filterByGenre. The argument I'm passing in is giving me an error which is props.id.toString().

Comment: It's just as the error says. `id: number | null` means that the `id` may be null.

Comment: ok how do I fix it

Comment: By figuring out what logic you want when the ID is null, and then implementing it.

Answer (score -1):

ok thanks I figured it out.

```
onclick{() => {
   if(props.id !== null) {
     props.filterByGenre(props.id.toString());
   }
}
```